# Angular 6 + Universal Karma testing importing modules

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, angular-universal

### Problem

I'm currently trying to test my Angular 6 application with Karma, and I keep bumping into errors like the following:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'.
```

When I import it in this single component it does work, but then in another component I have to import it again..

Example of one of the test files now with the imports:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AdminOverviewComponent } from './admin-overview.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatTableModule, MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';

describe('AdminOverviewComponent', () => {
  let component: AdminOverviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AdminOverviewComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AdminOverviewComponent ],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatTableModule, MatSelectModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdminOverviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Is there a possibility to import all the modules I declared in my app.module.ts into all the modules Karma is generating?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each test `spec` file should be independent from others. So you have to reconfigure everything (that is required for the component testing) inside each test `spec` file.

As far as I know, There is no such global configuration to import modules, declare components etc..

In your case you have to do,

`imports : [FormsModule]` in all the specs where `ngModel` is used

Comment: Well if it was only the FormsModule related stuff failing it would be ok, but I also get errors on my HTTPClient being used in my services, errors on custom pipes I'm using etc.. If I have to import all of them just to run the tests it's a lot of work. :(

Comment: You should be doing that, There is no way to escape. This way, you keep your specs independent and also you only import the modules that are necessary for that component.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old one but, in case someone else comes here looking …

Angular automagically adds a `/src/test.ts`- by default it looks something like this:

```
declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Here you can add any global modules - for instance the FormsModule like so:

```
// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  [
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    MatIconTestingModule, // Say i'm annoyed that tests fail whenever I add an icon.. I'll add this here
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    // Add any additional modules here
  ],
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

This list shouldn't be that big - generally you want your specs to be self-contained but I find this to be a practical way to avoid repeating the same imports over and over